# Как вывести из массива словарь, перед этим выводя первую букву следующих слов?

Tags: php, массивы, строки

Есть массив на латинице, содержащий слова. Массив отсортирован по алфавиту. Как вывести его в виде:

```
A
Слово на А1
Слово на А1
B
Слово на B1
```

и так далее
важно чтоб при отсутствии слов на определенную букву, сама буква не выводилась

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Собрать массив, где ключами будут первые буквы слов, а значениями - группы слов:

```
$words = [
    'Слово',
    'Сахар',
    'Алфавит',
    'Аммиак',
    'Спирт',
    'Что-то ещё'
];

sort($words);

$new_arr = [];

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $char = preg_split('~~u', $word, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)[0];
    $new_arr[$char][] = $word;
}

var_dump($new_arr);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=3)
  'А' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Алфавит' (length=14)
      1 => string 'Аммиак' (length=12)
  'С' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Сахар' (length=10)
      1 => string 'Слово' (length=10)
      2 => string 'Спирт' (length=10)
  'Ч' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Что-то ещё' (length=18)
```

---

PS: Этот пример работает и с латиницей.

---

Распечатать получившийся массив можно так:

```
$view = '<pre>';

foreach ($new_arr as $letter => $word_list) {
    $view .= "$letter<br>";
    foreach ($word_list as $word) {
        $view .= "\t$word<br>";
    }
}

$view .= '</pre>';

echo $view;
```

В результате:

```
А
    Алфавит
    Аммиак
С
    Сахар
    Слово
    Спирт
Ч
    Что-то ещё
```

Comment: есть проблема в том, что это уже и есть ассоциативный массив, где ключи - слова, а значения везде разные, и от слов никак не зависят, и каждое значение привязано к определенному слову-ключу. ваш способ подходит, но только для ключей, значения в этом случае теряются :\

Comment: @inDee а вы добавьте не большой фрагмент вашего массива в свой пост с вопросом - я подкорректирую свой пример.

Comment: разобрался сам, огромное спасибо)